# Increasing top position in masonry view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

In  masonry view, I want to increase top position. At the moment, the top position is set automatically. How can I increase it ?[image] from masonry js

My Jquery code

```
<script>$(document).ready( function() {

  $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 170,

    gutter: 20,

  });

});</script>
```

my html

```
<div class="grid">
                                    <?php 
                                    for($i=0;$i<count($img_arry);$i++){
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="grid-item">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $img_arry[$i];  ?>" width='' height='150' >
                                    </div>

                                <?php
                            }
                                 ?>
                                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: How about a link? More info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just add a few pixels of padding or margin to the bottom of your `grid-item`?

Comment: I already try using css but not working it..
masonry automatic add top & left position
<div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 140px;">
          
         </div>

Answer (score 0):

Actually I fixed the height & width of  grid-item , So this type of error occurred . Now removed  height & width of  grid-item from css and problem solved